# cannot click or write into textarea

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript

```
function edit(btn) {
div = document.getElementById(`div${btn.dataset.id}`)
post = document.getElementById(`post${btn.dataset.id}`)
post.remove()
let text_area = document.createElement('texarea')
text_area.textContent = post.textContent
text_area.setAttribute('rows','4')
text_area.setAttribute('name','contents')
text_area.setAttribute('columns','5')
div.append(text_area)
console.log(div)
```

}

I can see the contents of the textarea but cannot edit it. My html and css are simple so I think the problem is with javascript

> 

```
        <div id="creator_post">
            <h4 id="creator"><a href="{% url "profile" post.creator %}">{{ post.creator }}</a></h4>
            <h5 id="date">{{ post.date_created }}</h5></div>
        <div id="div{{post.id}}"><h6 id="post{{post.id}}">{{ post.contents }}</h6></div>
        <div id="creator_post">
        <h6 id="likes_num">{{post.likes_num}} likes</h6>
        <button class="edit_btn" data-id={{post.id}}>Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is css

```
#post_content{
    margin: 2rem;
    border: 0.3rem solid;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-color: grey;
    max-width: fit-content;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#creator_post {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 0.1rem;
}
```

Comment: but the HTML and CSS would help those who could be bothered to help you with your error

Comment: I will add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. The correct tag name for a text box is "textarea", not "texarea". And instead of "columns", use "cols".

Comment: oh okay thank you. I was looking for the mistake for the past hour.